# Nestjs HealthCheck decorator signature

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I upgraded @nestjs/terminus to 7.0.1
While refactor of my health indicator i see the typescript complains on decorator signature:
[image]

I checked with different typescript versions (Currently using 4.0.5)

Is it a bug?
Only me facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this issue and is not related to NestJS.
The issue related to Visual Studio Code typescript version compatibility.

Solved by updating Visual Studio Code IDE to version 1.51.1